# I can not seem to get a cookie to be set in my vue.js app

Tags: vue.js, authentication, cookies, vuejs3

I'm going around in circles with this and so far spent hours trying to work it out. So I have an api endpoint `/login` that returns a token and I want this token to be stored in a cookie called token in my Vue.js frontend so I can reference it to other routes - `POST/PUT` etc.

I'm using `js-cookie` as the package (have been trying with `vue-cookie` but no luck) and I can't get the cookie to be set even though I can see it logged right above it.

```
async onSubmit() {
      try {
        const response = await this.$store.dispatch('login', {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        });
        console.log({ token: response.token }); << this logs out {token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIU.....'}
        Cookies.set('token', response.token, { expires: 1 });
        this.checkToken(); // Check if the token has been set
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error logging in:', error);
      }
    },
```

But then when I check the cookie with

```
checkToken() {
      const token = Cookies.get('token');
      if (token) {
        console.log('Token is set:', token);
      } else {
        console.log('Token is not set.');
      }
    }
```

I get `Token is not set` returned.

For completeness here is the `login` action from the `store.js` too -

```
async login({ commit }, credentials) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/login',
          credentials
        );
        const token = response.data.token;
        Cookies.set('token', token, { expires: 1 }); // Set the cookie to expire in 1 day
        commit('SET_LOGGED_IN', true);
        commit('SET_USER', response.data.user);

        return { token }; // Add this line to return the token
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error logging in:', error);
      }
    },
```

I can see that the API is returning the token in Postman and the console.log, not sure what I am missing here as to why it's not being set? As you can see I have even tried setting it in both the action and the method, no luck!

Many thanks!

I have tried switching out cookie packages and moved the configuration around the application numerous times but can't see to work it out.

Comment: Update on the above, seems to be a Chrome issue as the cookies are storing in FireFox. Just need to work out why Chrome is not allowing cookies to be set.

Comment: Your code looks good so far. If it works in Firefox so your Chrome must have some setting that prevents setting cookies. It's `your Chrome`, not Chrome browser in general